# Firestore emulator missing some collections after being successfully launched

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I've been trying to launch a test/copy firestore in my local emulator and everything is great, except for one thing: my firestore emulator is missing collections and stops working because of unknown reason.

I have exported prod Firestore DB to local storage as 'some_date.tar' extention and unarchived this file to my project root. After which I have run `firebase emulators:start --import ./firestore-local-data` (i am already logged in to firebase and project is selected). The emulator runs correctly and functions are working, but when you go to UI of the emulated Firestore you can not open all collections and view them. For example smaller collections work just fine, but as soon as I open the huge one it all breaks and I can no longer open even smaller if I had not opened them before the huge one. I enabled flow control in my Windows 10 as traceback suggests but it didn't help. I also noticed that when I click on the 'department' collection I get 400 Bad Request. Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you!

I enabled flow control in my Windows 10 as traceback suggests but it didn't help. I also noticed that when I click on the 'department' collection I get 400 Bad Request. Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you!  PS. Can't post images because of low reputation

Comment: When you first click the large collection, is there any error showing either in the browser - or in the terminal window where you started the emulators?

Comment: On the UI part no errors, but if you look at the Network section, there is 400 Bad Request. I have a fear that the problem is in the sheer size of the collection 'department'. Emulators might simply not be capable of working with such datasets (146 mb). Could not find any proof to this, but everything else works just fine
Edit: also no errors in terminal or logs

Comment: Since the emulators run locally on your machine, they indeed have size limitations that you won't see in the production database. But I would expect it to log a different error than the `400 Bad Request` when it's out of memory.

Comment: Endpoint where it breaks (GET): `http://127.0.0.1:10010/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2F{myProjectId}`
I double checked and saw no logged error messages in all consoles  except for Java 

`Nov 01, 2022 5:05:56 PM com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.BackChannel add
WARNING: Failed to send a new message due to too many pending messagings in the back channel (10001). May need enable flow control.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I checked with our engineering team, and this seems to be a known issue **in the Firestore emulator** indeed (as you suspected) related to the size of the collection.

There currently is no known workaround aside from using less data. In case that is not possible, I recommend following along with (and potentially chiming in on) issues [#4672](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4672) and [#5197](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5197) in the source repo.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and effort. I found a workaround for the developing purposes (in my case): what I did is I effectively made a replica or copy if you like (as you suggested) and with a smaller sample of data I could make that work and develop happily. Have a great day!

Comment: Good to hear that worked for you @NazariiHorchytsia 